# Can accelerations be used to calculate load factors?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, aircraft-physics, load-factor

Can I use the z accelerations to calculate the load factor in that axis? Please explain how or why not.

Comment: Highly related to this other recent question/answer: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/71511/how-does-the-load-factor-vary-when-the-aircraft-pitches-up-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure can; in fact, they are equivalent (with an offset of 1G).

In the body frame, the vertical equation of motion is:

$$Z+mg\cos\theta\cos\phi=m(\dot{w}+pv-qu)$$

Accelerometers can't measure inertial or gravitational forces, so vertical acceleration as measured is $N_z=Z/m$.

Comment: What do you mean by "accelerometers can't measure inertial or gravitational forces"? That's exactly what they measure.

Comment: @Zeus I mean exactly what I wrote. An accelerometer under free fall will measure no force.

Comment: Yes, and there will be no load. This is precisely because it measures _both_ the gravitational force _and_ the inertial force of the acceleration, which add up to zero. A static accelerometer will measure the gravitational force (acting on its sensor) at its location and will not show zero, despite zero acceleration.

Comment: @Zeus A static accelerometer on a table top shows 1G because it's measuring the normal force (Z in the expression). If it's measuring the gravity component as well, then it should read zero. What I wrote and what you wrote above are equivalent.

Comment: Well, you can say it's a philosophical question, because you can always claim that the accelerometer 'actually' measures the reaction of its internal spring (if we assume a classic weight accelerometer). But this is an 'implementation detail'; it's _meant_ to measure the gravitational (and inertial) force.

Comment: @Zeus This is not merely an implementation detail. Inertial forces (e.g. coriolis, centripetal) aren't actually forces; that's why they are called fictitious forces. Gravitational forces are special too, hence the elevator equivalence principle.

Comment: They are not 'actually' forces, but an accelerometers measures exactly them, rather than the acceleration per se. In an orbit/turn, it will indicate a force away from the centre (centrifugal), instead of the centripetal acceleration that causes it. It is a matter of our _interpretation_ to move from one to the other.

Comment: @Zeus I don't want to dwell on this since it's offering no value to the question. Obviously, the inertial forces cannot exist without the external forces. But the point is, you "measure" one _or_ the other. I choose to express measurement as body forces minus gravity here. Moved to chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100915/discussion-between-jimmy-and-zeus